# Sharing PC's ethernet connection with laptop

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

I hope this is the correct place to ask this question.

**Question: I would like to share internet between my PC and Laptop (Apple MacBook).**

On my work PC I have access to internet through ethernet. I can access internet through WiFi on my laptop but my office is too far away from the access point so the connection is not stable, it keeps logging me off too.

My first option is to ask ISS, who require me to hand in my laptop. They want to check it for malware, pirated software etc and register my MAC address. **I don't want to give them my laptop so they can go through my personal stuff**.

Is it possible to use some kind of hardware to share internet from my PC to laptop. I have seen USB to ethernet adapters. But I assume they work as external NIC. What I need is a device to bridge internet connection between 2 device.

FYI, I don't have admin rights to install new drivers on my work PC which has Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set up the wireless connection as a bridge to the MacBook using Internet Connection Sharing ([ICS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/using-ics-internet-connection-sharing)).  Its relatively easy to set up, unless your IT department has disabled it.

And speaking of your IT department, what you are doing sounds like a violation of your companies IT policies.  They are in the right, asking to inspect any device that goes on *their* network.  By connecting your MacBook to the network without their consent, you could open yourself up to disciplinary action.

Comment: That's not possible, because ICS requires Administrator rights.

Comment: ah, does it?  I dont remember.  Still, the second part still hold true

Comment: True, always ask your admin first. :)

Comment: The only reason I don't want to give them my laptop is they take ages to return it back. Secondly I can't un-install certain software (which i use at home) for them for example I wouldn't download torrents at work but they will object to having torrent client and other stuff like this.